# How should we make a compound adjective of an intransitive verb?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, compounds

> I saw a man-eating alligator.

> She has a man-crying poem.

Eat is a transitive verb. The man-eating alligator is one that eats man. It is fine to me. But the confusion is that if we make it as “She has a man-crying poem”

Does ‘a man-crying poem’ make sense? I have never seen anyone using “She cries him“.  But she makes him cry. (That is, she forces him to cry.).

Comment: Yes, "man-eating" corresponds to the VP "eat men". But "man-crying" does not correspond to "cry men". You cannot "cry a man" (or men), so it makes no sense.

Comment: You'd use something else like a *tear-jerking poem* or a *heart-wringing poem* where *jerk* and *wring* are transitive.

Answer (score 1):

No, **a man-crying poem** doesn't really make sense (although it might be understandable).  As you point out, the problem is that *cry* is not transitive: you can't say "she cries him" to mean "she makes him cry".

You can easily use this kind of **object-verbing** construction with transitive verbs:

- a song that **breaks hearts** : a **heart-breaking** song
- a story that **soothes children** : a **child-soothing** story
  etc.

But it doesn't work with intransitive verbs, because there is no object to put there:

- a dog that sleeps (no object) : a ___ sleeping dog

You could use a construction with *that* and another clause, like "a poem that **makes men cry**", but then there isn't really a construction to make that into an adjectival form.  I guess you could say "a **making-men-cry** poem" and be understood, but it is an ugly and non-fluent way to say it.